# Anylogic Error: Can't Convert from Population to Resource Pool

Tags: anylogic

I am a new Anylogic user and I am trying to set up a simple simulation like so:

1. I have one ResourcePool named `People`.
2. `People` uses a Schedule named `People_Schedule` that is sourced from a DB table that has a date column and then the number of resources (employees) avalailable that specific interval.

`2020-07-09 10:30` `32`
`2020-07-09 11:00` `35`
`2020-07-09 11:30` `40`

3. I have a par of Sources named `G_Task` and `M_TASK`.
4. Both of these Sources use Schedules that are sourced from a DB that has one column with a date column, a work type column, and then a number of work items (tasks) expected for that specific interval.

`2020-07-09 10:30` `M` `100`
`2020-07-09 10:30` `G` `50`
`2020-07-09 11:00` `M` `125`

5. I have a specific Service for each of my Sources, but my issue is that when selecting the ResourcePool setting in Properties, there is no dropdown for my ResourcePool named `People`.  I can type in `People` which then allows both items to be highlighted at the same time on the grid like maybe they are linked, but when I hover on the error I am getting on the Resource Pool setting, I get this message:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Main._People_Population to ResourcePool`

What am I missing?  I have tried searching through the Anylogic help and through Google, but I am finding nothing.

As a side question, are there any Anylogic users that have gotten past the learning curve and are comfortable with the level of troubleshooting out there on the web (or lack thereof)?  I am used to being able to search SQL/Excel/Python questions and finding tons of resources almost immediately.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Hi, the AnyLogic community is much smaller than SQL/Excel/Python (orders of magnitude!). Here and the LinkedIn Forum are your best places. Or direct AnyLogic support

Comment: re your error, it seems that your ResPool is not in the same agent type that your service. Either put them into the same agent type (or both on Main) or you must use code to specify the resource-pool by navigating through your model hierachy to find it... share details about who lives where, add a screenshot as well for clarity